# How to get the value of a cell displaying time, as text, in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, time

I have cell `C4` with the value `1:05:20` and I'm trying to create a string `TIME 1:05:20` and paste this string into another cell `C5` using VBA but am not getting what I need. My code below returns 
`TIME 4.53703703703704E-02` instead.

```
Public Sub timer()

Range("C5").Value= "TIME" & " " & Range("C4").Value

End Sub
```

How can I get the required value?

Comment: `Range("C5").Value= "TIME" & " " & Range("C4").Text` if you want the exact same formating.

Comment: @VincentG That works perfecly too cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is a proper time you have to format it. To Excel dates and times are just numbers, it's the formatting that makes them look like dates or times. (A time is a fraction of a day, hence your answer.)

```
Range("C5").Value = "TIME" & " " & Format(Range("C4").Value, "hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: My pleasure. See also Vincent's comment.